# How to properly set selected state through @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this Drop down list in my view I'm trying to wire up to a model in my MVC4 web application.

Here is a property on my model object:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Used to provide values in the type drop down list in.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SomeTypes
    {
        get
        {
            var someTypeNames = new [] { "abc", "def", "xyz" };

            var someTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ESomeType)).Cast<EsomeType>();
            var someTypesSelectItemsList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            someTypesSelectItemsList.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Selected = true,
                Text = "Choose a type",
                Value = "-1"
            });
            foreach (var eSomeType in someTypes)
            {
                var sli = new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Selected = false,
                    Text = someTypeNames[(int)eSomeType],
                    Value = ((int)eSomeType).ToString()
                };
                someTypesSelectItemsList.Add(sli);
            }
            return someTypesSelectItemsList;
        }
        set { }
    }
```

Here is the model property on which I'll bind my dropdown later in my view:

```
[DataMember, Required]
[Display(Name = "Type:")]
public virtual int SomeType { get; set; }
```

Then I print this in my view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SomeType)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeType, new SelectList(Model.SomeTypes, "Value", "Text"), new { ng_model = "type", ng_change = "ChangeType()" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SomeType)
```

Now this all works fine (I'll refactor more later), but my problem is with the rendered html:

```
<label for="SomeType">Type:</label>
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Type: must be a number." data-val-required="The Type: field is required." id="SomeType" name="SomeType" ng-change="ChangeType()" ng-model="type">
    <option value="-1">Choose a type</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="0">abc</option>
    <option value="1">def</option>
    <option value="2">xyz</option>
</select>
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="SomeTypeType" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

As you can see, the "abc" option is selected="selected" and not my "Choose a type" one and we can clearly see the code in my model sets the proper one to selected. What's going on here?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem happens when the model-binding variable has the same name as the select list.

Try this changing the name of your `SelectList` to **SomeTypesList**

In you **Model**:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SomeTypesList
```

and in your **View**:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeType, 
                      new SelectList(Model.SomeTypesList, "Value", "Text"),
                      new { ng_model = "type", ng_change = "ChangeType()" },
                      "Choose a type"}
```

---

**Followup note:** you are setting your default value in your select list rather than your helper

Comment: It does not appear to fix my issue. I'll edit my question and add the model property to which I'm binding this.

Comment: Yup they were named differently. One singular one plural as one represents a "chosen value" and the other one the possible values. I have crossed other questions mentioning what you said, but it did not seem to apply in my case. I'm sure it's something very silly I'm just not seing...

Comment: @SébastienRicher, I think I understand. You seem to be trying to set your default value in your select list instead of inside your helper. Please see my example of how to set default value. Add "Choose a type" as last param to helper and remove from select list. both are important.

Comment: If I do these changes I get compilation error. I can put my "Choose a type" text as the 3rd parameter, pushing my "attributes" object as the 4th parameter and that runs. Nonetheless the problem persists and "abc" is still selected.

Comment: For reference, I tried this : "@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeType, Model.SomeTypesList, "Choose a type", new { ng_model = "type", ng_change = "ChangeType()" })" and got the same results. "abc" is the selected one.

Comment: @SébastienRicher, if you get compilation error, somethings wrong. try something, remove the attributes temporarily to see if code will build and work. If yes, we'll see what syntax will fix attributes

Comment: Ok I got it working now! I think something in my angular was screwing something up! Let me test some things for a minute.

Comment: Yes it was a combination of issues, what you mentioned was right and I have an issue further down with the angular in my page! All sorted out now! Many thanks for the help!

Comment: @SébastienRicher, glad to help. these dropdowns are a pain!